# Xcode complains about translation of Image

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsimage, nsbutton

I'm in the process of localizing my fist Cocoa Application. I translated all nibs and created `.string` files. All fine.

In one of my nibs I have a `NSButton` and I assigned `NSStopProgressFreestandingTemplate` to the Image property.

[image]

When I now start my application, it shows the following output in the debug frame:

> Localizable string "NSStopProgressFreestandingTemplate" not found in strings table "AccessibilityImageDescriptions" of bundle CFBundle 0x1gu5c0401db0  (executable, loaded).

The image is still shown but I want to get rid of that message. Where expects Xcode from me to define this string? I put it into the `.string` file of the containing nib with no effect.

I searched the whole project for `NSStopProgressFreestandingTemplate` and it only occurs in the Image property of my button:

[image]

Also a search for `AccessibilityImageDescriptions` does not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna take a wild guess here and say that you mistakenly also set "NSStopProgressFreestandingTemplate" as the accessibility identity description in Interface Builder?.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is not the case. The Accessibility Identifier is empty.

Comment: Try to search on Xcode for "NSStopProgressFreestandingTemplate" to see where else it is set (Search on xcode 6.1 also includes storyboard(s)).

Comment: Sorry, I should have noticed that. I did that and the only occurrence is in the NSButtons image property. I updated the question with a screenshot of the search result.

Answer (score 0):

It suddenly stopped complaining. I sure changed lot of things in my project in the meantime but did not actively check if or which of those changes solved the "problem".

Here are some of the things I remember I did between yesterday and now:

- Restarted Xcode and the system... you never know!
- Removed and re-added base internationalization (checkbox in project info tab)
- Added a new language

Maybe that helps someone who experiences the same issue.